# I need to put my results in order that get from mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json, classification

I have a database table like below:

```
id | igroup | title     | url          | text
1  |   gr1  | Title 1   | urltoimage1  | text1
2  |   gr1  | Title 2   | urltoimage2  | text2
3  |   gr2  | Title 3   | urltoimage3  | text3
4  |   gr2  | Title 4   | urltoimage4  | text4
```

**I mean, i want to have an multidimensional array (for above structure) like below;**

```
$result[gr1] = [Title 1|urltoimage1][Title 2|urltoimage2]
$result[gr2] = [Title 3|urltoimage3][Title 4|urltoimage4]
```

Finally, I'll send this `$result` array to page via JSON.

So, in my page I'll arrange these values for classified image gallery, like:

```
Group 1(caption text)
--------
image1 image2 (clickable images)

Group 2(caption text)
--------
image3 image4 (clickable images)
```

Edit: i corrected group field by igroup.

Question revised.

Comment: `group` is a reserved word in mysql. You may want to give that column an alias before ordering.

Comment: @Blaine - order by group field

Comment: @Matt - let me correct the name in question

Comment: `select id, \`group\` as myGroup, ... order by myGroup`

Comment: I'am not talking about oredering in MySql. I want to fetch results and put them in an array (structure given in Question) then send to page via JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fetch the results using the `ORDER BY` statement added to your query.

```
SELECT id, igroup, title, url, text
FROM images
ORDER BY igroup;
```

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Example code:

```
$result = mysql_query(THE_STATEMENT_ABOVE);

$groups = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
    $groups[ $row['igroup'] ][] = $row;
```

This will build up a nice `$groups` array. To parse the array created above, you might either use [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) constructs.

```
foreach ( $groups as &$one_group ) {
    print("Group 1: <br>");

    foreach ( $one_group as &$one_image ) {
        // Here you have the contets of the previously fetched $row rows of the result.
        print('<a href="' .$one_image['url']. '">' .$one_image['title']. '</a><br>');
    }
}
```

This will give you a nice output like this below:

```
Group 1:
Image 1 (clickable)
Image 2 (clickable)

Group 2:
Image 3 (clickable)
Image 4 (clickable)
```

**No longer applies:** Also, you should refrain from using `GROUP` as a field name, as it is one of the [reserved MySQL words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

**Edit:** I have also corrected the field name to `igroup`.

Comment: that is what i've been looking for.. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to ask additional question about your solution. I have 6 images in db, when i execute your function 6 image links are put correctly but there is an additional line that returns NULL. Why this happen? Thanks again.

Comment: Call a `var_dump()` on `$groups` after the `while(){}` construct, then put the output on [Gist](http://gist.github.com). We'll look into it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/0648793f953ac9a8b858/9cbc472e5cd97f9beb4478e9d7f48bd78dd116a2

but values are Turkish :)

Comment: It might be that the inner foreach's `print` line prints a `<br>` linebreak after the last element was processed, as your array dump seems to be intact.

Comment: now problem is: Always Group 1 is written for all captions, how to print Captions correctly for each group?

Comment: If your group has a `caption` field you can get from the result, you just have to alter the `print("Group 1: <br>");` line to fit your needs.